# type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds:view and tablayout

Tags: android

I have the error when I initialize the tablayout findViewById(R.id.tablayout)
p can someone assist

```
    Tablayout tablayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablayout);
        tablayout=findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    }
}

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1db995">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"/> 


'''
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
```

instead of this

```
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

Note: If it's not the right answer for you, can you explain a little bit more? For example you can copy paste whole xml and activity. Also can you send the error completely?